# Unable to place my input cursor focus on textbox

Tags: html, css

I create this form and I wanted to be like this position. But somehow I cannot put my cursor focus on `Bank Name , Address , Country` because it redundant. Any idea how to fix this?

```
.grid2 #col2 {
  padding-left: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
}
```

[Demo in here](https://jsfiddle.net/2u3wa850/)

Comment: To quick fix this add `z-index: -1;` to `.grid2 #col2`

Comment: tq for the suggestion, but it need to go through first textbox's first, and need to tab tab until `account number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the position: absolute; from the CSS and you will be able to put your cursor in the box.

If you want to have the components side by side you can either float them to the left or use a flexbox layout.

Comment: since I beginner here, never heard this flexbox yet. Thank you for the idea and I will try

Answer (score 1):

I would reconsider how you have coded this. While there are quick fixes it will not get you very far before a new related issue arises.
You can break it down like this. You need 2 columns which can be achieved like this:

`<div class="container">
    <div class="content1">
        ...ul > li elements....
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
        ...ul > li elements....
    </div>
</div>`

`.container { display:flex; align-items:flex-start; }`

Your labels in the li need about `width:30%` and the input `width:69%;` to be safe. floated left.

Look into [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and from there you should be able to make something more responsive and robust.

Answer (score 0):

In your css, the ".grid2 #col2" sets the padding to be 500px to the left.  What you want here is margin not padding.   Padding is the spacing IN the imaginary box while margin is the space outside of the box.  You cannot see the cursor because you are actually clicking on the imaginary box for the #col2 inputs.  Change this to margin and you cursor will be visible in your intended input field.

```
.grid2 #col2 {
   padding-left: 500px;  <-- change this to margin-left: 500px;  --- 
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
}
```